# psql "more is not recognized" error

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I am using the postgresql (9.4) interactive terminal psql on Windows 8.1 (64 bit). After installing and creating a database and table and inserting data into a row I want to view the data.

However, when I type

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

I get an error:

> 'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

After adding "C:\Windows\System32;" to my path variable, more works in Powershell (e.g. more hello.txt) but still not in psql.

What else do I need to do to make the SELECT statement work?

Comment: Setting C:\Windows\System32 in your system path variables works. However, you may have to restart your computer for the update to take effect. At least, that's what I had to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like the way you are launching *psql*, `C:\Windows\System32` is not actually on the `PATH` in the resulting environment.

You can download something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and use it to look at the environment variables for the running *psql* process and see if that path is present.

If not, you could make sure it's set in the shell from which *psql* is invoked, set it as a system environment variable, set `PATH` accordingly in a *cmd* file and then invoke *psql*, etc.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32
```

Comment: You're right, I had only updated the PATH variable for my current user instead of for the system, so when I launched psql under a different user it didn't see the C:\Windows\System32 statement. This is despite searching for "system environment variables" in Windows, since there were still two boxes - one for local user and one for the system.

Answer (score 4):

Typically this error occurs due to *PATH* environment variable is not set
properly in your system & it is unable to find the more command from

> *C:\Windows\System32.*

The solution to this is:

> (Right Click on)  My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced tab ->
>   Environment Variable ->

Then set the `PATH` in system variables.

Add these to the PATH variable:

- `%SystemRoot%;`
- `%SystemRoot%\system32;%PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Open the **SQL shell** and type in

`\pset pager off`

Answer (score 2):

Keep below contains in `create_PG_script.bat` file

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
@echo off
setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32
set PGPASSWORD=yourpasswordcomeshere
"C:\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432 -f D:/PG_Script/select_query.sql"
pause
endlocal
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Also create separate `select_query.sql` file same location keep

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////
select * from company;`enter code here`
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

run the `create_PG_script.bat` file

Answer (score 2):

If Editing and setting Environment Variables doesn't work, One reason might be your terminal may not be able to show the output. So please off the pager by typing "\pset pager off" in the prompt and retry again.

Answer (score 1):

We need to set the path :-

"more" exists in C:\Windows\System32. So, please set the path in PATH 
Environment Variable. and then try.
My Computer (Right Click) -> Properties -> then go to Advanced tab -> 
Environment Variable -> set the path.

Comment: This is by far the most straight forward and accurate response on this thread. This worked immediately and effectively, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

set the path for the psql in PC settings(right-click)->environment variables->system variables->path(click edit)->" **C:\Program Files\Postgresql\12\bin;C:\Program Files\Postgresql\12\lib** " now check on the terminal one more time

Still, this problem occurs check on c>windows>system32>

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do two things.

1. Set the path from  My Computer (Right Click) -> Properties -> Advanced system settings  -> Environment Variable -> path -> Edit -> add (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\YourVersion\bin).
2. If that doesnot work then disable pager.

   \pset pager off

Answer (score -1):

on your cmd terminal command

\pset pager off

and then retry