# AWS CLI: "'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to list all of the EC2 instances running on in my AWS account. I am doing this through the AWS CLI on Windows 10. However, the command is giving an error:

```
> aws --version
aws-cli/2.7.28 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 ee/AMD64 prompt/off

> aws ec2 describe-instances
'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: And in response to your question, what's your PATH set to? Ensure you have `C:\Windows\System32` on your system PATH.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714719/psql-more-is-not-recognized-error